# Mobile Webpage with fixed width to support multiple devices

Tags: javascript, xhtml, mobile-safari, viewport

I came to a problem on the later stage of a project for a mobile page. Client asked to support both iPhone and various android mobile devices instead of supporting iPhone only.

The mobile page was written in XHTML, with html page width 640px, and its elements have width,e.g. 500px, %20... so the page look great in iPhone's safari with the following viewport, but ugly in other devices's browsers.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width, target-densityDpi=device-dpi,initial-scale=0.5, maximum-scale=0.5, minimum-scale=0.5;">
```

I was trying to solve the problem by playing with viewport, but have being struggling for a long time. My idea is about the initial-scale, can someone suggest a way to dynamic assign this value = device-width/640 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should just use:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=320">
```

Why 320? It's because although the iPhone 4's screen is 640 pixels wide in portrait, it's a "retina" display with twice as high effective dpi as desktop screens. Hence it has a window.devicePixelRatio of 2, which means that its device-width is only 640/2 = 320 CSS px, i.e. each CSS px takes up a 2x2 square of physical device pixels (see [this article on QuirksMode](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html) for more details).

This 2x scaling is very useful, because for example you can set font-size:14px and the perceived size of that text will be the same as if you viewed 14px text on an iPhone 3G (since it will actually be displayed using 28 physical device pixels on the iPhone 4, which compensates for the higher dpi). If instead your font-size:14px text was shown using only 14 physical device pixels, it would look tiny on the iPhone 4 (half the size that it would on a iPhone 3G).

Now, there is a consequence of this: your site has to be designed for 320px width, not 640px. But that was already true, since iOS has never supported target-densityDpi=device-dpi, so by putting width=device-width you were effectively putting width=320 anyway.

So why use width=320 instead of width=device-width? Since you say that your site is a fixed-width layout, then with width=device-width it is likely to look bad if it is shown on different size devices, for example you might see a white margin down the right hand side on wider devices, whereas with width=320 the browser will scale it up to fit the device's screen width (it may therefore look somewhat enlarged, but that's probably better than having a white margin).

However, please just consider this a stop-gap measure: it would be much better to keep width=device-width, and modify your site design to be flexible instead of fixed-width (for example set width:100% on your divs and images instead of width:320px). For more information, see http://www.html5rocks.com/en/mobile/responsivedesign/

Finally, you can keep the ", user-scalable=no" term if you really don't want the user to be able to zoom in and out, but for accessibility reasons it's often better to omit this, unless you're designing something like mobile maps.google.com, where you're manually handling pinch zoom gestures and you don't want to browser to interfere.